# Error: FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations in my GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When trying to run my flutter + firebase app, I keep getting errors like this 
Note: /Users/chykeofficial/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I've followed the help provided in the official documentation but it isnt resolved

Note: /Users/chykeofficial/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.